# Failed to get a 1:1 aspect ratio video in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I tried to get 1:1 aspect ratio video in WebRTC.

But when I use this setting, I still get a 4:3 aspect ratio video.

```
constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: { width: 240, height: 240 }
};
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/wqof6pq7/6/).

How can I do it correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. After adding latest [adapter.js](https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-1.0.7.js) (version 1.0.7) as external resources, it works perfect now.

The codes no need change, still same

```
constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: { width: 240, height: 240 }
};
```

The working jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/wqof6pq7/8/).

Hope this helps people who has similar problems.

Comment: This answer won't work in all browsers. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36962250/918910).

Comment: If you're interested why this didn't work before, it's quite simply because constraints are not fully implemented yet, they work in javascript, some work in the native API's. Even the ones that work have a list to choose from instead of allowing arbitrary numbers. It seems like your new version of adapter.js fixed some of the issues with constraints you were running into ;)