# How to get webcam stream with aspect ratio 1:1 and maximum available resolution

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

Basically the question is in the title. This is about WebRTC and getUserMedia function. Similar question was here: [How to keep 1:1 aspect ratio video all the time in WebRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961228/how-to-keep-11-aspect-ratio-video-all-the-time-in-webrtc). But in my case I need to record a stream using MediaRecorder, just crop a video element with css is not enough.
I'm a bit confused about getUserMedia constraints. There is aspectRatio parameter, but I didn't manage how to achieve required result with it. What worked for me was to define constraints in that way:

```
const constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: {
    width: { exact: 720 },
  }
};
```

But it doesn't define max resolution automatically. Do you have any ideas how to do it in a smart way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep 1:1 aspect ratio video all the time in WebRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961228/how-to-keep-11-aspect-ratio-video-all-the-time-in-webrtc)

Comment: @jib yes, that question is similar, but I need a stream to record it using MediaRecorder. Just crop a video element with css is not enough.

Comment: `aspectRatio` is not implemented in Chrome or Firefox yet. However, it sounds like you expect getUserMedia() to rescale the camera output for you. Not all browsers do this, instead letting you discover native modes of your camera, so this may fail with OverconstrainedError instead.

Comment: It seems that `aspectRatio` is working on the latest Chrome now, although I can't find any information about that. However, at least the `min` and `max` constraint did work for me on Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all cameras are going to support all aspect ratios.  `1:1` is certainly an oddball aspect ratio.

What you have to do is do your own cropping and make your own stream.  You can do this by setting a video's `srcObject` to the getUserMediaStream, then every frame (use `requestAnimationFrame()`), draw that video to a canvas, in whatever cropped way you want.  From there, use `CanvasCaptureMediaStream` to get the edited video back out as a stream which you can use in your WebRTC call.