# Cannot apply constraint (16x9) to webrtc video in firefox 54.0.1

Tags: firefox, constraints, webrtc

Unable to set video resolution to 16x9 in Firefox 54.0.1, it gives error OverconstrainedError: Constraints could be not satisfied.

You can check given fiddler location.

`Fiddler Link`: https://jsfiddle.net/34qxx5w1/162/

It is supported in version Firefox 47 and 48, also it works in chrome too.

Comment: Unlike Chrome, Firefox does not rescale to whatever you want, instead letting you discover native modes of your camera, so results depend on your camera. What OS are you on, and what camera do you have?

Comment: My OS is Windows 8.1 and Web cam is Iball CHD 20.0. 

I see that Chrome crops the video base on constraint applied, same is not true for Firefox.

Comment: I think you mean Chrome rescales, not crops. Firefox's behavior is actually the right one, according to [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#dom-constrainablepattern-applyconstraints()). Why else would there be a whole constraints language? - Your fiddle asks for `640x360` exactly, not any 16:9 mode. Can you tell me more about the problem you're trying to solve? To crop playback, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36962250/918910).

Comment: Chrome does crop the video, yes it crops if you apply video constraints, same is not true for Firefox. Firefox shows `640x480` as output whatever video constraints you apply. You can see the screenshots for Chrome `640x480` https://i.stack.imgur.com/nePdI.png and `640x360` https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQcuR.png.

Comment: You're right, Chrome crops in this particular case. Chrome rescales and crops. Again, not the intent of the spec. I'm not sure what your question is. You can crop playback instead as I show.